# 12 Days of Christmas in Rust

Tags: rust

I've recently been trying to learn more rust and I have just finished [chapter 3 of the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-05-control-flow.html#summary), which has a list of projects to do to practice.

I have tried to write a program that prints the 12 Days of Christmas and I would like to know if it is idiomatic or if any major improvementsc could be made.

Thanks in advance.

```
const LYRICS: [&str; 12] = [
    "Twelve drummers drumming",
    "Eleven pipers piping",
    "Ten lords a-leaping",
    "Nine ladies dancing",
    "Eight maids a-milking",
    "Seven swans a-swimming",
    "Six geese a-laying",
    "Five golden rings",
    "Four calling birds",
    "Three french hens",
    "Two turtle doves, and",
    "A partridge in a pear tree",
];

fn gen_lyrics(day: i32) -> String {
    let ordinal = match day {
        1 => "1st".to_string(),
        2 => "2nd".to_string(),
        3 => "3rd".to_string(),
        _ => day.to_string() + "th",
    };

    let mut start = format!(
        "On the {} day of Christmas, my true love gave to me:\n",
        ordinal
    );

    for i in (0..day).rev() {
        start.push_str(&LYRICS[11 - (i as usize)]);

        if i != 0 {
            start.push_str("\n");
        }
    }

    start
}

fn main() {
    for i in 1..13 {
        println!("{}\n", gen_lyrics(i))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This looks pretty good! I'm still fairly new to Rust myself, so I'm not sure how familiar I am with the idioms beyond those outlined in the book. That said, there's a few improvements I can suggest.

### Unsigned integer for `day`

Since `day` is never negative, you can use an [unsigned integer](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-02-data-types.html#integer-types) instead of an `i32` here:

```
fn gen_lyrics(day: usize) -> String
```

If you use `usize` specifically, you also avoid the cast to `usize` here:

```
start.push_str(&LYRICS[11 - (i as usize)]);
```

That would then just be:

```
start.push_str(&LYRICS[11 - i]);
```

### Ordinal suffix `match` expression

You can avoid some `.to_string()` calls and repetition of numbers by making the match expression return just the suffix of the ordinal. You can then append that suffix to the number itself in the `format!()` call:

```
let ordinal_suffix = match day {
    1 => "st",
    2 => "nd",
    3 => "rd",
    _ => "th",
};

let mut start = format!(
    "On the {}{} day of Christmas, my true love gave to me:\n",
    day,
    ordinal_suffix
);
```

### Inclusive range

You can use `..=` instead of `..` to create an [inclusive range](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/data-types/inclusive-ranges.html):

```
fn main() {
    for i in 1..=12 {
        println!("{}\n", gen_lyrics(i))
    }
}
```

### Iterators and the skip method

You can iterate directly over the `LYRICS` array, [skipping](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.skip) over the number of lines you don't want to include:

```
for line in (&LYRICS).iter().skip(12 - day) {
    start.push_str(line);
    start.push_str("\n");
}
```

The problem with this is that there's no longer an `i` variable to check whether an iteration is the last line or not, so it can't conditionally insert a newline. The code above will always insert a newline.

But we can cheat a little

If you remove the newline from the end of the `start` variable:

```
"On the {} day of Christmas, my true love gave to me:"
```

You can push the newline first, that way you no longer need a conditional in the loop:

```
for line in (&LYRICS).iter().skip(12 - day) {
    start.push_str("\n");
    start.push_str(line);
}
```

---

### Bringing it all together

This is the code with all the changes applied:

```
const LYRICS: [&str; 12] = [
    "Twelve drummers drumming",
    "Eleven pipers piping",
    "Ten lords a-leaping",
    "Nine ladies dancing",
    "Eight maids a-milking",
    "Seven swans a-swimming",
    "Six geese a-laying",
    "Five golden rings",
    "Four calling birds",
    "Three french hens",
    "Two turtle doves, and",
    "A partridge in a pear tree",
];

fn gen_lyrics(day: usize) -> String {
    let ordinal_suffix = match day {
        1 => "st",
        2 => "nd",
        3 => "rd",
        _ => "th",
    };

    let mut start = format!(
        "On the {}{} day of Christmas, my true love gave to me:",
        day,
        ordinal_suffix
    );

    for line in (&LYRICS).iter().skip(12 - day) {
        start.push_str("\n");
        start.push_str(line);
    }

    start
}

fn main() {
    for i in 1..=12 {
        println!("{}\n", gen_lyrics(i))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this great answer - I hope to see more from you in future!

Comment: I think you can just `start.push_str((&LYRICS).iter().skip(12 - day).join("\n"))`

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I think you can only `join` on a slice, not from an iterator, so you'd have to do `start.push_str(&LYRICS[12 - day..].join("\n"))`. Note that this will allocate to make the `String` of the lyrics joined together, then copy that into `start`.

Comment: [What's an idiomatic way to print an iterator separated by spaces in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36941851/155423)

Comment: *no longer an `i` variable to check* — [`Iterator::enumerate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.enumerate).

Comment: `(&LYRICS).iter()` can just be `LYRICS.iter()`

Comment: Thanks for the great answer -- this has been invaluable and has taught me a lot, definitely motivated me to keep learning!

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone! I also learned some new things here :D

@OllyBritton I'm glad to have helped! If my answer helped sufficiently, could you mark it as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)? Thanks!